# Rules of escaping characters in Android and ios strings

Tags: android, ios, string, localization, escaping

I'm wondering in `strings.xml` and `localizable.strings`, what are the treatments towards single(') and double(") quote and also line breaks.

My understandings are:

1. `string.xml` needs all single and double quotes to be escaped. e.g. `I\'m` or `\"story\"`

2. `localizable.strings` only needs the double quotes to be escaped. e.g. `\"story\"`

3. line breaks in `string.xml`will need to be represented by `\n`

4. line breaks in `localizable.strings`can be either `\n` or literal line breaks.

Are my understandings correct? Please let me know if other differences. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are absolutely right!

Comment: @YunCHEN Thank you very much Yun!

Comment: ;) . You did it!